# C++11 construct in place confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use a vector as a part of a custom storage container. I want to avoid any temporaries when adding objects to the container, and I want to manually construct objects in-place of previously free'd objects. How can I do this without creating temporaries?

The code:

```
struct Mesh
{
    float data;

    Mesh(float a) : data(a)
    {
    }
};


template<typename T>
class IDStorage
{
public:
    template <typename... Arguments>
    void AddItem(Arguments&&... args)
    {
        if (!mFreeIndices.empty())
        {
            const uint32_t freeIndex = mFreeIndices.back();
            mFreeIndices.pop_back();

            // mItems[freeIndex] = Item(0, 1, args...);     NOPE - I want to avoid this temporary!
            // mItems[freeIndex].Item(0, 1, args...);   NOPE
            // new (&mItems[freeIndex]) Item(0, 1, args...);     NOPE
            // How can I avoid a temporary in this case?
        }
        else
            mItems.emplace_back(0, 1, args...);
    }

    void FreeItem(uint32_t index)
    {
        mFreeIndices.push_back(index);
        // ignore destructor
    }


private:
    struct Item {
        uint32_t mIndex;
        uint32_t mVersion;
        T mItem;

        template <typename... Arguments>
        Item(uint32_t index, uint32_t version, Arguments&&... args) : mIndex(index), mVersion(version), mItem(args...)
        {
        }
    };

    std::vector<Item> mItems;
    std::vector<uint32_t> mFreeIndices;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IDStorage<Mesh> meshStorage;
    meshStorage.AddItem(1.0f);
    meshStorage.FreeItem(0);
    meshStorage.AddItem(2.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply assign to `mItems[freeIndex]`?

Comment: Why do you use vectors instead of lists here?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something elementary but how do I assign without creating a temporary in the process? Also I must have contigous memory but also compact storage

Comment: Ah, I see, you pass around an arbitrary number of arguments to *construct* a new object from. In that case, you could either require `mItem` to have some assignment-like function that takes those parameters, or you could manually call the destructor and re-create an object at the same place (using placement new). The latter has a pitfall though: you may not reuse pointers to the original object depending on what `T` is (but you'll get a new pointer from placement new anyway).

Comment: First option is only as a last-resort if there is no other way. Second option, I do not quite understand the pitfall you mention. Placement new creates a new object at given memory address? So why would that be a problem?

Comment: E.g. if you try `auto* p = &mItems[freeIndex]; p->~Item(); new(static_cast<void*>(p)) Item(0, 1, args...); do_something_with(p);` then the behaviour can be undefined depending on properties of the type `T`. If you however write `auto* p = &mItems[freeIndex]; p->~Item(); p = new(static_cast<void*>(p)) Item(0, 1, args...); do_something_with(p);`, the behaviour is well-defined (note the assignment of `p`). Placement-new is very low-level code and can get you easily into the realms of UB even with subtleties.

Comment: An example: If `T` has a `const` data member, the compiler may assume it never changes. If you then do change it by destroying the object and re-creating a new one at the same place, the compiler might have cached the old value and might re-use that.

Comment: You mean new(&mItems[freeIndex]) Item(mItems[freeIndex].mVersion + 1, args...); causes trouble on some compilers due to optimizations but Item* foo = new(&mItems[freeIndex]) Item(mItems[freeIndex].mVersion + 1, args...); dosn't?

Comment: No, the issue is reusing pointers or references that have been created pointing/referring to the object *before* its destruction. Once the destructor is called, the object is no more, only its storage remains. Any pointer to it becomes invalid. Under certain circumstances, you may reuse that pointer if an object is created in the same place - but not in general.

Comment: @dyp This is interesting, and although I believe you're right I've never thought about this. Do you happen to have the relevant standard passage for this?

Comment: [basic.life], especially p7

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There have been a number of [tag:language-lawyer] conversations on the topic, usually relating to manual placement new.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way:

```
template <typename... Arguments>
void AddItem(Arguments &&... args)
{       
    if (!mFreeIndices.empty())
    {
        const uint32_t freeIndex = mFreeIndices.back();
        mFreeIndices.pop_back();

        // this doesn't create a temporary          
        //mItems[freeIndex].mIndex = 0;
        //mItems[freeIndex].mVersion = 1;
        mItems[freeIndex].mItem = T(args...);
    }
    else
    {
        mItems.emplace_back(0, 1, args...);
    }
}
```